# Intersection of two string array (ignore case)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, intersection

I have two arrays:

```
string[] array1 = { "Red", "blue", "green", "black" };
string[] array2 = { "BlUe", "yellow", "black" };
```

I need only the matching strings in one array (ignoring case).

Result should be:

```
string[] result = { "blue", "black" } or { "BlUe", "black" };
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

How about an [`Enumerable.Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408.aspx) and [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer_properties.aspx) combo:

```
// other options include StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
// or StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
var results = array1.Intersect(array2, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `results` will contain the values from `array1` and not `array2` with respect to case.