# How to find the placement of a List within another List?

Tags: c#, list, compare

I am working with two lists. The first contains a large sequence of strings. The second contains a smaller list of strings. I need to find where the second list exists in the first list.

I worked with enumeration, and due to the large size of the data, this is very slow, I was hoping for a faster way.

```
    List<string> first = new List<string>() { "AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF" };

    List<string> second = new List<string>() { "CCC","DDD","EEE" };

int x = SomeMagic(first,second);
```

And I would need x to = 2.

Comment: Can you show us what you have try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented SomeMagic method as below, this will return -1 if no match found, else it will return the index of start element in first list.

```
private int SomeMagic(List<string> first, List<string> second)
{
    if (first.Count < second.Count)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= first.Count - second.Count; i++)
    {
        List<string> partialFirst = first.GetRange(i, second.Count);
        if (Enumerable.SequenceEqual(partialFirst, second))
            return i;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what the doctor ordered. Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding using `GetRange` to avoid the cost of allocating the list repeatedly. `Take` would likely be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my variant with old-good-for-each-loop:

```
private int SomeMagic(IEnumerable<string> source, IEnumerable<string> target)
{
    /* Some obvious checks for `source` and `target` lenght / nullity are ommited */

    // searched pattern
    var pattern = target.ToArray();
    // candidates in form `candidate index` -> `checked length`
    var candidates = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    // iteration index
    var index = 0;

    // so, lets the magic begin
    foreach (var value in source)
    {
        // check candidates
        foreach (var candidate in candidates.Keys.ToArray()) // <- we are going to change this collection
        {
            var checkedLength = candidates[candidate];
            if (value == pattern[checkedLength]) // <- here `checkedLength` is used in sense `nextPositionToCheck`
            {
                // candidate has match next value
                checkedLength += 1;
                // check if we are done here
                if (checkedLength == pattern.Length) return candidate; // <- exit point
                candidates[candidate] = checkedLength;
            }
            else
                // candidate has failed
                candidates.Remove(candidate);
        }

        // check for new candidate
        if (value == pattern[0])
            candidates.Add(index, 1);
        index++;
    }

    // we did everything we could
    return -1;
}
```

We use dictionary of candidates to handle situations like:

```
var first = new List<string> { "AAA","BBB","CCC","CCC","CCC","CCC","EEE","FFF" };
var second = new List<string> { "CCC","CCC","CCC","EEE" };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/) then consider using `Window`:

```
var windows = first.Window(second.Count);
var result = windows
                .Select((subset, index) => new { subset, index = (int?)index })
                .Where(z => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(second, z.subset))
                .Select(z => z.index)
                .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

`Window` will allow you to look at 'slices' of the data in chunks (based on the length of your `second` list). Then `SequenceEqual` can be used to see if the slice is equal to `second`. If it is, the `index` can be returned. If it doesn't find a match, `null` will be returned.

Comment: upvote this as more elegant and more efficient way than an accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

you can use intersect extension method using the namepace `System.Linq`

```
var CommonList = Listfirst.Intersect(Listsecond)
```

Comment: This only shows me the items common to both lists. I'm searching large sequences of data looking for patterns.

Comment: i think you are asking for something like this do checkout:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301074/linq-compare-two-lists-and-count-subset