# Compare and extract common words between 2 strings

Tags: c#, string

In ASP.NET C# and assuming I have a string contains a comma separated words:

```
string strOne = "word,WordTwo,another word, a third long word, and so on";
```

How to split then compare with another paragraph that might and might not contain these words:

```
string strTwo = " when search a word or try another word you may find that  WordTwo is there with others";
```

Then how to output these common words departed with commas in a third string

```
string strThree = "output1, output2, output3";
```

To get a result like : **"word, WordTwo, another word,"**

Comment: What has this got to do with asp.net. isn't this just a C# question?

Comment: split `strOne` by comma and split `strTwo` by space. And then use `intersect` LINQ method to get the common words existing in both the arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323071/intersection-of-two-string-array-ignore-case

Comment: may be because i'm building an ASP.NET app :), shall  remove it :)

Comment: Do you want the the output to repeat the words or distinct

Comment: no just get them once  @TheGeneral

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to ***split*** strOne by comma, and use a ***contains*** against strTwo.

**Note:** You can't split strTwo by space and use intersect because your items may have spaces. i.e. "another word"

```
string strOne = "word,WordTwo,another word, a third long word, and so on";
string strTwo = " when search a word or try another word you may find that  WordTwo is there with others";
var tokensOne = strOne.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var list = tokensOne.Where(x => strTwo.Contains(x));

var result = string.Join(", ",list);
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew worked for me and testing both with different scenarios

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
        string strOne = "word,WordTwo,another word, a third long word, and so on";
        string strTwo = " when search a word or try another word you may find that  WordTwo is there with others";
        string finalString = string.Empty;

        foreach (var line in strOne.Split(","))
        {
            if(strTwo.Contains(line))
                finalString += (line + ",");
        }

        finalString = finalString.Substring(0, finalString.Length - 1);
        Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

Comment: Good answer. If you use a `List` for `finalString`, you can then `string.Join` it to make it comma separated.

Comment: If not `string.Join` then consider using `StringBuilder` for `finalString` instead of concatenating the strings each time.

Comment: strOne.Split(",") isn't valid. See hsobhy's comment

Comment: strOne.Split(',')  instead